# IIS 7.0 free hosting

Tags: web-hosting, looking-for-hosting, free, iis7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

i'm looking for a a website that offers free hosting on IIS 7.0 or IIS 7.5 other than Somee. Does anyone know such a site?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're going to be hard pressed to find a quality host free of charge. Throwing in a few bucks a month will get you *much* better quality of service a ton more features.